# Ionic v1 app crashes after iOS device OS update from v11 to v12

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am also facing similar issue.
I am having app in ionic V1 and it was working fine till iOS v11. As I updated my device to iOS v12, app stopped working/crashed. The only solution was to uninstall it and re-install the app (without any code change or code compile).

It doesn't affected to minor device OS updates yet but surely is very inconvenience for users.

Kindly advise.